# Push data to receipt printer

Tags: php, javascript, hardware, zebra-printers

I have a system in place where customers order their food through a php website. The order is sent to a mailaddress and saved in a db.

Now I want to add a new functionality and thats sending that data to a receipt printer in the kitchen, because thats what the guys there use. Its an Epson TM-T88IV. Only thing is, I have no clue how.

Is there an api for receipt printers? Or should I make a long polling node server and have some C script on a network computer listening etc...

Could you please push me in the right direction?

Gr.

Comment: Is the receipt printer attached to a PC or is it freestanding?

Comment: Its in the network, I can connect to it using every PC in the network

Answer (score 1):

There have been some printer-functions in PHP which might help you. However they are for Windows systems only and I do not know whether or not they still work...

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.printer.php

Answer (score 0):

You can set this printer as a default and use javascript code

```
window.print();
```

Comment: Wont that ask for a confirmation?